# Question about st_touches PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql

I'm working on a project of water supply which includes a layer representing the pipes. the operation that I want to do is generating a point layer where a pipe touches an other and then split it at this location. I found out that st_touches in PostGIS does it but I'm wondering if I can do it on the same layer because in the doc they were talking about two different layers or geomtries. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I answer your question but always is a good idea post the create table sentences and the queries that you are using now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you always can join a layer with itself. You only need to have a bit of care to not duplicate the results.

Assuming that id is the primary key of the table.

```
SELECT a.id FROM my_table a, my_table b
WHERE a.id < b.id AND ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom);
```

Comment: here is what I did : SELECT pipe.id FROM pipe b, pipe d
WHERE b.id < d.id and ST_Touches(b.geom, d.geom);                            and I got this error :  invalid reference for column id.

Comment: thanks it works.I had to specify it like this SELECT b.id, d.id FROM pipe b, pipe d WHERE b.id < d.id and ST_Touches(b.geom, d.geom);

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: Best practice is to use the `JOIN` clause.

Comment: Actually, for this kind self-joins i usually use the cartesian product and not a join. Can you point to a link suggesting why is a good practice? I will update my answer according to it. Thanks.